# Why CEF app is not rendering Polymer UI?

Tags: polymer, chromium-embedded

I have developed a web application using Polymer and packaging it as a CEF App. When I launch the application, I only get a blank screen while same application in browser is rendered properly. 
I'm using CefSharp (V- 1.19.0.41824) to embed a webView control in my winform application. Below is the code that I'm using for displaying web content in webView -

```
 webView = new WebView();
 webView.Load("http://localhost:8000/sampleApp/")
```

Any pointer will be very useful.

Comment: Can you give more info? Are there any errors in the Chrome dev console, are the Polymer files being loaded from your HTTP server?

Comment: When I access the same web app in chrome, it is working fine, rendered properly.Only in the webview control, it is not rendered. I don't know how to check if there are any errors while loading in webview. I tried opening polymer project's site also (http://www.polymer-project.org/) which is also not rendered. so I'm not sure if CEF supports Polymer.

Comment: Using CefClient (CEF3) polymer project's site renders fine. Check with [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) if content is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the current core chrome version used by CEF is lower than 36, then you'll need to enable the experimental flags to allow the web components features.

I don't know how you would enable those flags in your project, but I do know that web components and html link/includes where only made mainstream in the browser core from chrome 36 onwards.